# *.csv or *.txt export by using Framework7

Tags: javascript, export-to-csv, iphone-web-app, html-framework-7, export-to-text

Is there any possibility to export the content of an array to an *.csv or *.txt file by using Framework7?

The app will be used on the iPhone as a web app in Safari, so how can I save the exported file then? Can I directly save the file into my Google Drive or iCloud?

Thank you!

Markus

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to rely on framework7 to do that. framework7 is just a UI framework, anything that happen behind the screen can be done with a javascript / phonegap plugin.

[Check out this plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)